# My contact form is not working properly in django?

Tags: python, django

this is the application where a random users can fill the contact form and can send message to the admin.
This code is not sending email to my email address.

Error:
TimeoutError at /shop/contact/
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        #subject = form['subject'].value() tried this also
        #message = form['message'].value()
        #email = form['email'].value()
        recipients = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        send_mail(subject, message, email, recipients,fail_silently=False)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Message Sent.')
            return redirect('shop:contact')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Error in Form')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request,'shop/contact.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name','phone','email','subject','message']
```

contact.html

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<title>{% block title %}Contact{% endblock %}</title>

{% block content %}
 <center>{% bootstrap_messages %}</center>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
            <div class="card my-5">

                <div class="card-header text-center">
                   Contact
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% bootstrap_form form %}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-center w-100 mb-3" value="Contact">
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemailaddress'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_POST = '587'
```

Comment: Did you try letting your send_mail function fail loudly?

Comment: Please change `fail_silently` argument of `send_mail` function to `False` to see the problem.

Comment: i used fail_silently = False and the result is also the same

Comment: You should be using `form_cleaned_data['subject']` etc, not `form['subject'].value()`.

Comment: i tried this also and its now giving me a TimeoutError it says TimeoutError at /shop/contact/
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: You are using `form.cleaned_data['email']` as the `from_email`. Many email providers will not let you do this. You should send email messages from an address that the email account owns, e.g. `youremail@gmail.com`, and use the [`reply_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) option if you want replies to go to a different address.

Comment: In addition, if you search stack overflow for gmail and Django, you will see many users facing issues trying to send emails from Django with gmail. You might want to investigate using [django-anymail](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail) and a transactional mail provider.

Comment: Alasdair can you please help me to change this code

Comment: Since you have a timeout error I don't believe the problem is with the message you're sending, but with the connection to gmail. Do you use 2 factor-authentication on the account you're trying to use? If so, then just username/password doesn't work, you need to generate an app-specific password.

Comment: Have you enabled less secure apps in Gmail? Check this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) out. It may be triggering the timeout, although I believe the stacktrace should be more verbose if this was the issue.

Comment: yes i have enabled less secure apps but still not working